# sql construct a tree by hanging it from a leaf

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 tables (only relevant columns given) as

table j

```
id int
account int
amount numeric;
```

table e

```
id int
account int
amount numeric
code_id foreign key to j.id
```

data sample

table j

```
  id   account_id   amount     
 ---- ------------ -------- -- 
   1            5      500     
   2            6     -700     
   3                           
   4            6      200     
   5
```

table e

```
  id   account_id   amount   code_id  
 ---- ------------ -------- --------- 
   1           10     -200         1  
   2            6     -100         1  
   3            8      150         1  
   4            7     -350         1  
   5           12      200         2  
   6           13      500         2  
   5            6      200         3  
   6            4     -100         3  
   7            6     -125         3  
   8            5       25         3  
   9            6     -200         4  
  10            6      300         5  
  11           12     -300         5
```

I want for each account_id in either table j or table e the following. I give the result for account **6**

**Edit: Need to take 6 and hang it upside down listing all transactions against it as follows.**

```
  ledger_head_id   account_id   amount   bal   t_id  
 ---------------- ------------ -------- ----- ------ 
               6           10     -200            1  
               6            8      150            1  
               6            7     -350            1  
               6            5      500   100      1  
               6           12      200            2  
               6           13      500   700      2  
               6            4     -100            3  
               6            5       25    75      3  
               6            6     -200   200      4  
               6           12     -300   300      5
```

what I have done is

```
WITH tb1 AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT code_id AS j_id, account_id, amount, 'E' AS entry_type, e.id AS entry_id
        FROM t, e
        WHERE code_id = t.id
        UNION ALL
        SELECT id, account_id, amount, NULL, NULL
        FROM t
    ) foo
    WHERE account_id NOTNULL
)
    SELECT
        DISTINCT ON (l2.account_id, j_id)
        j_id,
        l2.account_id AS ledger_head_id,
        jsonb_agg(
            jsonb_build_object(
                'account_id', l1.account_id,
                'amt', l1.amount,
            )
        ) OVER ( PARTITION BY l2.account_id, l1.j_id ORDER BY l2.account_id, l1.j_id ) AS details,
        l2.amount
    FROM tb1 l1
    LEFT JOIN tb1 l2 USING (j_id)
    WHERE
          ((l1.entry_type = 'E' AND l1.entry_id IS DISTINCT FROM l2.entry_id) OR ((l1.entry_type != 'E' OR l1.entry_type ISNULL ) AND l1.account_id != l2.account_id))
    ORDER BY ledger_head_id, j_id
```

I feel, this is not an optimum way of doing it. 
Just for information, it is not necessary for me to join the whole tables...I could do it for an account required as(ledger_head_id) if that will can be more efficient, then I have to use **functions in Postgres**.

Basically looking for a better way to do it.

**Using: Postgres 12**

Thank You

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name..how do you format the text so fast. Any info will help me in future. Thanks

Comment: I use https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/